# Flutter Error: Provider cannot access route in navigation

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

When I run this I keep getting the same error , kindly assist.

```
 Future<void> main() async {
          WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
          await Firebase.initializeApp();
          runApp(App());
        }
    
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color primaryColor = Color(0xff18203d);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ignore: todo
    // TODO: implement build
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          Provider<AuthenticationService>(
            create: (_) => AuthenticationService(FirebaseAuth.instance),
          ),
          StreamProvider(
            create: (_context) =>
                _context.read<AuthenticationService>().authStateChanges,
            initialData: null,
          ),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'Mboka Horticulture',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: primaryColor,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          home: AuthenticationWrapper(),
        ));
  }
}

class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthenticationWrapper({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ignore: todo
    // TODO: implement build
    final firebaseuser = context.watch<User>();
    if (firebaseuser != null) {
      return Dashboard();
    }
    return Login();
  }
}
```

This is the error I keep getting and I  don't understand.

> **Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a
> route, then
> other routes will not be able to access that provider.
>
> ```
> - You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.
>
>   Make sure that AuthenticationWrapper is under your MultiProvider/Provider<User>.
>   This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.
>
>   For example, instead of:**
> ```

Comment: is this a provider? AuthenticationWrapper , add code snippets of this please

Comment: AuthenticationWrapper is a stateless widget

Comment: do check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62418382/about-errors-that-occur-in-flutters-provider

Comment: @griffins AuthenticationWrapper is a stateless widget

Comment: you are creating and using your provider all in the same Widget Main so everything on the same BuildContext, and when you run context.watch<User>(); flutter will try to look up in your Widget tree to find the Model but it won't find it because you have just created it  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62418599/10409567

Comment: @griffins  So how do I solve the error coz I have already tried using the example given.

Comment: this provider has not been registered ,  final firebaseuser = context.watch<User>();

Comment: try using `changenotifierProvider` ` ChangeNotifierProvider<MyProvider>(create: (context) => MyProvider()),` then in your build method use `var myProvider = Provider.of<MyProvider>(
      context,
      listen: false,
    )`
your data will be available here myProvider.